# How to make the bot invoke itself?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've tried to make an on_message and invoke messages send by the bot

My code so far:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

but this doesn't invoke any commands made by anyone

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `discord.ext.commands.Bot` from the commands extension of the library.

Check how the [`self_bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.self_bot) optional argument when initializing the bot works. By default it is False, and so the bot will always ignore himself. However if it is True, it will not listen to other users or bots.

Also, instead of `if not a == b` use `if a != b`.